# How to make a field on Opp Line item searchable

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, content-search

we are using Opportunity Products and pricebooks. So we have different line items on an Opportunity.

Every line item (opp product) has an autonumber and other unique entries.

Is it possible to make one field searchable? I read something about an external ID field but not sure if that helps in this case.

I just need to be able to search and find an Opportunity product, the limitation here on standard SF is pretty useless.

Thanks for any tips!

best,
Tanja

Comment: What do you mean by searchable? Search box, SOSL, SOQL?

Answer (score 1):

[OpportunityLineItem](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm) is not searchable. Note how the docs no not show "search()" as a supported operation. You could use SOQL on a Visualforce page, but it won't perform the same as a SOSL search.